# How can i add my intertitial ad to this code in eclipse?

Tags: admob

Hello everyone i want that someone help me to add the intertitial admob code to this game, there just the banner code but what i want is showing the banner on the screen for all the time not just when the message be show. and this is the codes:

- Mainfile.java:

---

```
package com.boontaran.games.chickenrun;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Fields;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.MapBuilder;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class ChickenRunAndroid extends AndroidApplication implements Ihandler {
    private ChickenRun game;

    private RelativeLayout layout;


    //IMPORTANT, change this...
    //admob
    private final String admobId = "###"; // change with your ads id, if not using ads, leave it blank --> ""
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adscontainerParams ;
    //analytics
    private final String trackingId = "UA-69568893-33";// change with your tracking  id, if not using it, leave it blank --> ""


    //OPTIONAL
    // share message
    private final String shareTitle = "Chicken Run";
    private final String shareBody = "Hi, check out this grat game : ";

    //ads
    private AdView adView;
    private RelativeLayout adsContainer;

    //analytics
    private Tracker tracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);


        //main app layout
        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setContentView(layout , params);

        //the game
        game = new ChickenRun(this);
        View gameView = initializeForView(game);
        Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_NONE);

        //add game to view
        layout.addView(gameView);

        setupAdmob();
        setupTracker();
    }
    private void setupTracker() {
        if(trackingId.equals("")) return;

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // debug --> analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);

        tracker = analytics.getTracker(trackingId);


    }
    @Override
    public void sendMessage(int message) {
        if(message==ChickenRun.SHARE) {
            shareGame();
        }

        else if(message==ChickenRun.HIDE_BANNER) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(ChickenRun.HIDE_BANNER);







        }
        else if(message==ChickenRun.SHOW_BANNER) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(ChickenRun.SHOW_BANNER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void trackEvent(String name) {
        if(tracker ==null) return;

        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Game", "action", name, (long) 1 ).build());
        Gdx.app.log("PenaltyChallengeAndroid", "event="+name);
    }
    @Override
    public void trackScreen(String name) {
        if(tracker==null) return;

        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, name).build());
        Gdx.app.log("ChickenRunAndroid", "track screen="+name);

    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what ==ChickenRun.SHOW_BANNER) {
                if(adsContainer == null) return;
                showBanner();

            }
            else if(msg.what ==ChickenRun.HIDE_BANNER) {
                if(adsContainer == null) return;
                hideBanner();

            }
        }

    };

    private void showBanner() {
        layout.addView(adsContainer,adscontainerParams);
    }
    private void hideBanner() {
        layout.removeView(adsContainer);
    }
    private void shareGame() {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

        //set the data
        String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

        String body = shareBody+"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+packageName;
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareTitle);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

        Gdx.app.log("ChickenRun", body);

        //start the share activity
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }

    private void setupAdmob() {
        //not using admob
        if(admobId.equals("")) return;

        //container
        adscontainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        adsContainer = new RelativeLayout(ChickenRunAndroid.this);




         // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(admobId);

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

        //.addTestDevice("635E0169A7DF83F621390AF96B6F06F7")

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bannerContainer2);

        Gdx.app.log("ChickenRunAndroid", "load ads");
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Gdx.app.log("ChickenRunAndroid", "ad loaded");
                if(adView.getParent() == null) {
                    Gdx.app.log("ChickenRunAndroid", "ad showed");



                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                    adsContainer = new RelativeLayout(ChickenRunAndroid.this);


                    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    adsContainer.addView(adView,lp);


                }
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Gdx.app.log("ChickenRunAndroid", "ad failed");
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

            }

        });
    }

}
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation for integrating interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en).

Go through it and insert the required code in your activity. Dont expect someone to just do it for you so that you can copy and start using. Try it and if you face problems let me know and I'll try to help.